# How to make string from pl/sql be seen as json response in an ajax call from FancyTree?

Tags: jquery, json, plsql, fancytree

I'm having an issue while populating a FancyTree tree via the ajax call option.  The source of the page and the tree data is PL/SQL package from an Oracle 10 database.  I call `tree_test.show_page` and it uses `htp.p` to display this simple test page (script links removed for clarity):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tree Testing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    // Create the tree inside the <div id="tree"> element.
    $("#tree").fancytree({
      checkbox: true, // Show checkboxes.
      debugLevel: 2,  // 0:quiet, 1:normal, 2:debug
      selectMode: 3,  // 1:single, 2:multi, 3:multi-hier
      source: {
        url: "tree_test.get_tree",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true
      }
    }); // end of fancytree def
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Tree structure:</p>
<div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The tree doesn't display, but in the Chrome debugger I can see where the call to `test_tree.get_tree` was successfully made.  I'm assuming that the issue is that the string response is not being seen as JSON data.  I know the data is good because if I add `var treeData = <JSON data here>` and change the FancyTree `source` parameter to `source: treeData`, it works fine.  And the tree data is supplied by the same PL/SQL procedure regardless of which way the `source` parameter is configured.

In the Chrome debugger, it shows the content-type of the response as <strike>text/html</strike> (see edit below).  I've tried various values for the `dataType` parameter ("json", "html json", "text json", "html text json", etc) with no success.

Am I missing something obvious??

Below is the sample JSON data:

`[{title: "Root Group", key: "g0", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [{title: "Group 1", key: "g1", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [{title: "Node 1", key: "141", tooltip: "Node 1"},{title: "Node 2", key: "82", tooltip: "Node 2"}]},{title: "Group 2", key: "g2", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [{title: "Node 3", key: "91", tooltip: "Node 3"}]}]}]`

Edit:
By suggestion of Yogi, I added `owa_util.MIME_HEADER('application/json', true)` to the `tree_test.get_tree` procedure and now the content-type of the response shows as `application/json` in Chrome's debugger.  But the tree still doesn't get populated with data.

Comment: can you paste sample data you are getting in response.

Comment: @AmitChotaliya: I've added the sample JSON data to the question.

Comment: @Yogi:  There is no java code to add to.

Comment: from `tree_test.get_tree` make sure response Content-type is `application/json`

Comment: @Yogi:  The response is not generate by java, it's generated by PL/SQL using `htp.p`.  I don't know of any way to set the content-type differently with that.

Comment: `OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER('application/json', FALSE);` maybe this will help

Comment: @Yogi:  I added that to the `get_tree` procedure and Chrome shows the response content-type as `application/json` now.  But the JSON data displays (in the debugger) as part of the header info.  If I set the second param to TRUE, it then displays as the 'response' instead of 'headers'.  But it still doesn't display as the tree data in the web page.  This is with the `dataType` set to `"json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* valid JSON data, but a JavaScript object dump:

```
[{title: "Root Group", key: "g0", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [{title: "Group 1", key: "g1", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [{title: "Node 1", key: "141", tooltip: "Node 1"},{title: "Node 2", key: "82", tooltip: "Node 2"}]},{title: "Group 2", key: "g2", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [{title: "Node 3", key: "91", tooltip: "Node 3"}]}]}]
```

it should be

```
[{"title": "Root Group", "key": "g0", "folder": true, ...
```

See http://json.org/

Comment: Aha, I (obviously) completely missed that!  Made the change and now it works!  But do you know why it works fine without the quotes around the 'name' portion of the name/value pairs if I a js variable (ie, `var treeData = <JSON>`) and set the source param to use that variable??

Comment: Nevermind, I just read the answer on your TutorialLoadData page: a javascript array can be passed that way.